# How to run a shell command with a sub shell with PHP's exec?

Tags: php, bash, shell, command, exec

Running this command with PHP's exec gives me syntax errors, no matter if I run it directly or put it in an extra file and run that.

```sh
time (convert -layers merge input1.png $(for i in directory/*; do echo -ne $i" "; done) output.png)
```

I think the problem is that it creates sub shells, which exec doesn't seem to be able to handle.

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: could you provide the actual error message?

Comment: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to simplify the command: remove the outer `()` which you dont need.

you could replace `$(for i in directory/*; do echo -ne $i" "; done)` by
just `directory/*` or  if you are
worried about empty dirs then `$(shopt -s nullglob; echo directory/*)`

```
time convert -layers merge input1.png directory/* output.png
```

or

```
time convert -layers merge input1.png $(shopt -s nullglob; echo  directory/*) output.png
```

Comment: The simplified command works, but I'd still like to know what exactly is wrong with the original one, because it works perfectly when ran from the shell.

Comment: @user923487 no I didnt see anything wrong with it either.